# Display HTML element only in text browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, lynx

I have a layout that looks well in normal browsers, but in links and lynx is looks like a large jumble of text. I'd like to add a `<hr>` or `<br>` between sections in the text browsers, but I don't want them to interfere with the CSS layout in normal browsers. I tried setting `hr {display: none;}` in the CSS, but it's also hiding it in the text browsers.

Comment: Text browsers applying CSS? ***Shocking.***

Comment: try to use <link rel='stylesheet' media='tty' href='lynx.css' /> to specify the css that will show br and hr only for media using a fixed-pitch character grid.

Comment: @kawashita86 works great, you should add an answer for that

Comment: thanks, i've added the answer as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE 21/12/2016:**
tty will be deprecated (along with a lot of other media types that you can check here https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#media-types) and should be substituted with a combination of media feature, a method that is a more fine-grained test than media types, testing a single, specific feature of the user agent or display device.
For targeting a text browsers you can ty with a combination with the [grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#descdef-media-grid) plus [monochrome](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#descdef-media-monochrome) feature.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

As Paul stated, you should use the media queries to let the browsers select the css that suits better for the device/browser.
For text browser, such as lynx and links, you should use the following media query:

**tty**

that is the format suited for media using a fixed-pitch character grid.

To target CSS rules you can import the css files with `<link>` tag specifing the media like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='tty' href='lynx.css' />
```

or by defining the media inside a css file  using the following syntax :

```
@media tty {
    my-lynx-css-rule {
        ...
    }
}
```

for a detailed description of the available media queries, please check the following page:
http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html

Comment: media type tty is deprecated http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I wouldn't use w3schools as a reference. Related MDN entry regarding deprecated media types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_types